# How to pass two parameter to a Query java

Tags: java, jdbc, parameters, integer

So I am trying to execute a query that takes 2 int values from the user however I am getting this error message. What I am doing wrong?

"at least one parameter to the current statement is uninitialized"

This is my Query

```
selectStudentsInRange = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT* FROM Results WHERE total BETWEEN ? AND ?");
```

An this is my method, yes is not the whole code.

```
public List< Results > getTotalMarksInRange( int value1, int value2 )
 {
  List< Results > results = null;
  ResultSet resultSet = null;

  try 
  {
      selectStudentsInRange.setInt( value1, value2 ); // specify id

     // executeQuery returns ResultSet containing matching entries
     resultSet =  selectStudentsInRange.executeQuery(); 

     results = new ArrayList< Results >();
```

Please notice that this is not the whole code I have many classes I am just wondering what is my error in this part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> at least one parameter to the current statement is uninitialized

```
selectStudentsInRange.setInt( value1, value2 ); // specify id
```

Change to

```
selectStudentsInRange.setInt(1, value1 ); 
selectStudentsInRange.setInt(2, value2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

That should be:

```
selectStudentsInRange.setInt(1, value1);
selectStudentsInRange.setInt(2, value2);
```

The first argument is the parameter index, the second argument is the parameter value.

See the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setInt-int-int-).

Answer (score -1):

> Take a look to this [Parameters For-PreparedStatement](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077706/core-java/named-parameters-for-preparedstatement.html)

```
selectStudentsInRange.setInt(1, value1 ); //this is how to set First Argument.
selectStudentsInRange.setInt(2, value2 )  // Set Your Second Argument.
//but make sure value1 and value2 both are Integer Type
```